# I want to return "Action" in GENRE column for all the movies that contain a certain string or starts with "Sp" using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to return "Action" in GENRE Dataframe/column for all the movies that contains or starts with "Sp" using pandas.

For Example:

```
Movies    Rating   Genre
Spider    4.8      Action
Spies     2.5      Action
Special   5.0      Comedy
```

I've tried 'str.contains' method but still no luck

Comment: Make your question (title) more generic. Rephrase "return action in genre dataframe/column". The meaning is unclear. Give an example of the expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code will return the Genre containing 'Action' and the Movie name containing 'Sp' as its substring.

```
df.loc[(df['Movies'].str.contains('Sp')) & (df['Genre'] == 'Action')]
```

The below code will return the Genre containing 'Action' alongwith the Movie name starting with 'Sp'.

```
df.loc[( df['Movies'].str.startswith('Sp')) & (df['Genre'] == 'Action')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your DataFrame (`df`) is:

```
    Movies  Rating   Genre
0   Spider     4.8  Action
1    Spies     2.5  Action
2  Special     5.0  Comedy
```

You can filter the DataFrame with:

```
import pandas as pd
df[(df.Genre == 'Action') & (df.Movies.str.startswith('Sp'))]
```

The output will be:

```
   Movies  Rating   Genre
0  Spider     4.8  Action
1   Spies     2.5  Action
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `loc` to filter your frame using boolean indexing and assign a value to a column. Change the string in `startswith` and `contains` to whatever value you want.

```
df.loc[df['Movies'].str.contains('es') | df['Movies'].str.startswith('Sp'), 'Genre'] = 'Action'
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is efficient way or not but you can do following:

```
def filter(x,y):
    if x[:2]=="Sp": return "Action"
    else: return y

df["genre"]=df[["Movies", "genre"]].apply(lambda z: filter(z.Movies, z.genre), axis=1)
```